# SQL Server : multi CASCADE Operation

Tags: sql-server-2012, cascade

I have two tables, and I want HEDE2 columns as FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES by HEDE table. FOR creating second table it will not allow because its having warning:

> More than one key specified in column level FOREIGN KEY constraint, table 'HEDE2'.

But when I tried to `ALTER TABLE HEDE2` for FOREIGN KEY it allows me to do that. Is anybody knows WHY this happens. Is this a bug?

```
CREATE TABLE cascde.HEDE
(
    HedeID INT,
    HedeID2 INT,
    HedeID3 INT

    CONSTRAINT PK_HEDE 
        PRIMARY KEY (HedeID, HedeID2, HedeID3)
)
GO

CREATE TABLE HEDE2
(
    Hede2ID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1) ,
    HedeID INT,
    HedeID2 INT,
    HedeID3 INT

    CONSTRAINT FK_HedeID 
        FOREIGN KEY (HedeID, Hede2ID, HedeID3)
        REFERENCES cascde.HEDE (HedeID, HedeID2, HedeID3)
           ON UPDATE NO ACTION
           ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

Altering table HEDE 2 for foreign key. This allows me to do that:

```
ALTER TABLE cascde.HEDE2 
  ADD CONSTRAINT FK_HEDE 
      FOREIGN KEY(HedeID, HedeID2, HedeID3)
      REFERENCES cascde.HEDE (HedeID, HedeID2, HedeID3) 
          ON UPDATE NO ACTION 
          ON DELETE NO ACTION 
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a comma (`,`) after `HedeID3 INT` in the `CREATE TABLE` version.